# GEN3's 10nm-30nm Contiuum Radiation Measurements

Tags: experimental-physics, plasma-physics, photon-emission

What is the most likely explanation for the 10nm-30nm continuum radiation reported in "[Validation of the Observation of Soft X-ray Continuum Radiation from Low-Energy Pinch Discharges in the Presence of Molecular Hydrogen](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260402802_Validation_of_the_Observation_of_Soft_X-ray_Continuum_Radiation_from_Low-_Energy_Pinch_Discharges_in_the_Presence_of_Molecular_Hydrogen)" by [GEN3 Partner](http://www.gen3partners.com/)'s [Alexander Bykanov](https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexander-bykanov-583b6b10)?

The abstract claims:

> Spectra of low-energy high current pinch discharges in pure molecular
>   hydrogen and helium were recorded ... showing  continuum
>   radiation only from hydrogen... continuum  radiation 
>   at  10.1  and  22.8  nm  and  going  to  longer  wavelengths ...  The
>   continuum radiation was observed at CfA in the 10–30 nm region that
>   comprised two bands with one having a short wavelength cutoff at about
>   10 nm and another was identifiable as a slope change on the first at
>   about 23 nm.  Considering the low energy of 2.6  J  per  pulse,  the 
>   observed  radiation  in  the  energy  range  of  about  120  eV  to 
>   40  eV,  and  reference  experiments  with  He ...

Comment: Let's just say... I don't trust any result from a plasma experiment that I haven't falsified myself. :-)

Comment: So these results are either unique or they provide grounds to investigate a criminal conspiracy to commit fraud?

Comment: No, I think CuriousOne just wants to say that a lot can go wrong in these experiments so one should wait until other groups can reproduce the results. That said - the passive voice in this abstract is really distracting. Did they do it or who did?

Comment: GEN3 Partners conducted the experiments at CfA.  Apparently they retained the services of Alexander Bykanov as PI for both the empirical and post-hoc theoretic analysis aspects.